# Saving Kinect Depth to Binary File

Tags: c#, matlab, kinect, depth

Apologises if this question has been asked before, I could not find it. However in general this forum has been amazing, programming is not my field of expertise ( I am from the medical side). However the kinect has presented some very interesting areas to explore. In nutshel, I am looking to save the depth data to a binary file to later analysis (and display) - while I am aware of the kinect studio, I need to record the data intandem with other data collected. I have searched around and adapted a method, however I am at a loss.

I hava created a call in the SensorDepthFrameReady method:

```
saveDepth(depthFrame)
```

The above passes the depthData byte[] array to saveDepth().

```
    public static void saveDepth( byte[] bytes)
    {   
    // create file io for write
    using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(file,     System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {            

        // write the passed byte buffer
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        // close the file
        stream.Close();
    }

}
```

This then saves to a .bin file. However, is this the correct format to enable access for later use in Matlab for example.

Comment: There are a lot of binary files so I am not sure whether this would work, maybe you can just try it. From a different perspective, why don't you just write it somewhere as text?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am asking if it is the correct way to save Kinect depth data to file. It does save it to a file however I am asking for validation for the method I have used is the correct way to extract the depth data. When I know it is in a file saved, I'll be able to work on it, however I just unaware if it is saving correctly.

Comment: There is no "right way" to save the data.  If it works for you, go for it!  Have a look at the "Kinect Toolbox" project on CodePlex, which provides recorders for all the streams - you can see how it is done there for ideas.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the direction of "Kinect Toolbox" I was already aware of it. I was just seeking if anyone was able to validate the method I have created does indeed save the depth data to file.

Answer (score 0):

To **validate** your method you should define what is correct and what is wrong.

If you write a corresponding method in MATLAB that can read the file you saved in C# and accomplish your job, it is correct, otherwise it is not.